# build okay locally, but fails in playground

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, plutus-playground, build

I am trying to compile the Homework01.hs
The build locally on Linux passes when I do :l src/Week02/Homework1.hs

```
Prelude PlutusTx Ledger.Scripts> :l src/Week02/Homework1.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Week02.Homework1 ( src/Week02/Homework1.hs, /home/xxx/plutus-pioneer-program/code/week02/dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.10.4.20210212/plutus-pioneer-program-week02-0.1.0.0/build/Week02/Homework1.o )
Ok, one module loaded.
Prelude PlutusTx Ledger.Scripts Week02.Homework1>
```

But when pasting the code in playground, I see an error :
[image]

Is this a playground problem or am I doing something wrong in Haskell ?

Just fyi, it does compile successfully in playground with the skeleton code initially provided by Lars at github.

The error description in playground doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy paste the whole file and just delete the line with

```
module Week02.Homework1 where
```

The playground does not need a module declaration (i guess it declares its own)

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the module export lines. That's not valid Plutus code but is useful for testing in a repl.